# WindowsForms: Following the Focus

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, listbox, focus

The Problem:
I have a custom `TextBox` that display a `ListBox` to give the user some suggestions what to type.
Now the thing is, that the `ListBox` needs to be hidden when the user leaves the `TextBox` with one exception. If the user clicks into the `ListBox`, the `ListBox` shall remain visible.

Is there any way to use the Leave or `LostFocus` events to find out if the next control is my `ListBox`?

---

Not the question but also interesting: Can you find out in a control which control was active before the focus changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TextBox.LostFocus` event handler, you can check for the property `ListBox.ContainsFocus` before turning off the visibility.

ContainsFocus property documentation:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `textBox_Leave` event check if the currently `ActiveControl` is your `ListBox`. If true, then `ListBox` got focused after you left `TextBox` and it shall remain visible, but if it's false, hide `ListBox`:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ActiveControl != listBox1)
        listBox1.Visible = false;
}
```